# Parallel execution in multiple devices using thread concept java

Tags: java, multithreading, testng, appium, concept

I am new to java. Please help. 
I had a requirement where I need to execute same test scenario in multiple devices in java. 
Also the requirement says my code should not execute in one devive alone,  it should initiate same scenario in multiple devices at a time.

Is it possible to execute at a time.

Note:
I have connected 3 devices at a time. 
But it executes same scenario one after other device.

I am uasing appium server and testng

Please help.. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test{

    WebDriver driver = null;
    int timeOut=180;
    int port=-1;

    Test(int port){
        this.port=port;
    }

    public void testEmulator(int p) throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.3");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Windows");

        capabilities.setCapability("udid","emulator-"+p);

        capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "your.app.pkg");
        capabilities.setCapability("app-activity",
            "your.app.pkg.Activity");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:"+this.port+"/wd/hub"),
        capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(50000);
    }

    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null)
            driver.quit();
    }

    public void runTest() {
        try {
            testEmulator(5554);     // for emulator on port 5554
            tearDown();
            testEmulator(5556);     // for emulator on port 5556
            tearDown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test(4723).runTest();       // appium server port 4723
    }
}
```

Comment: please let me know if it helps you

Comment: It's helps only for executing in one device.. but I need to execute in multiple devices

Comment: I gor ur answer.. but the server was started only once.. is that ok.. I am confused because till now I thought we Need to run multiple servers for every device.

Comment: please create as many WebDriver driver  as the no of device you want run on and the code will be ok.

Comment: I mean one server for one device.

Comment: try that and let see

Comment: And one more I can see that after execution of one device it executes in another device. But I need to execute in all the real devices at a time.

Comment: Dry to bug u. U have strated only one server 4733.  But if we execute in multiple devices and pass the same same desired capabilities will it create a problem..

Comment: please can you upvote if its helps you. while i do some testing on myside too

Comment: It's help only for executing one after other device. But I need to execute multiple devices in a single shot just like we use thebthreading concept

Comment: I need a sample code which can initiates  my execution in all devices at a time.

Comment: am testing that right now and update the answer very soon

Comment: have found any solution yet

Comment: I didn't find any solution

Comment: please are you on windows or mac?

Comment: i am thinking of a hack.let wrap the two servers arround the excutionService  of java.util.concurrency

Comment: Ok... let me try too.

Comment: just found this in their api and am trying to investigate what it does  ParallelThread parallelThread = new ParallelThread();

Comment: Did u get any solution.?

Comment: Oh,i thought u had a solution so i stoped researching

Comment: did u look at ParallelThread parallelThread = new ParallelThread();

Comment: can we chat on skype so that we may collabrate and solve the problem?

Comment: I dnt have net connection and only mobile net I have

Comment: Do u have any link to check parallelthread concept.. so that I can go through it

Comment: please let ask at this forum https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-parallel-execution-grid/4375/50

Comment: and this too  https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/speeding-test-execution-appium

Comment: https://github.com/saikrishna321/AppiumTestDistribution/blob/master/src/main/java/com/appium/manager/ParallelThread.java

Comment: please extend this class now AppiumParallelTest

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
public void startAppium() {
    //start appium instance
    try {
        Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 10000)); //wait from 0 to 10 sec for parallel process run
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(getCmd());
        builder.redirectOutput("path to log file"); //here you can find logs of appium
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        appium = builder.start();
        Thread.sleep(3000); //wait 3 sec until server started
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can understand that this code is for server starting but now I need a sample code on how to execute same test scenario in multiple devices all at a time.. please help